# System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, soap, .net-1.1, http-status-code-401, system.net.webexception

Ok, so I have this .NET 1.1 application (written by someone way back) which is like a document repository and it worked fine in the past. I suddenly get this error when trying to search for items/documents:

Page: /CPDEPforIT/SearchResults.aspx

Error:

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401:
>   Unauthorized. at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   CPDEPforIT.InktomiSearchService.soapSearchService.getSearchResults(SearchInput
>   in0) at CPDEPforIT.SearchResults.GetDatasetForSearchQuery(SearchInput
>   searchInput) at CPDEPforIT.SearchResults.Page_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain()

I don't remember any changes. Could this have been caused by something external to the application (IIS configurations/permissions, Server, Database)?

Comment: First thing I would check is that service accounts are still valid. It's easy enough for someone to change a password, or to lock an account.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to verify.

1. Does the web service you are trying to access allow Anonymous Access? Authentication can be tricky for web-to-web calls
2. What is the web application running under, IWAM_xxx or IUSR_xxx? Or are you using an application pool running under a specific identity?
3. You may want to make sure your web application server's ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICE accounts can access your web service server.

If you want to get it working you could just provide an account for Anonymous Access...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of issue before. In my case permission to the code folder works. Please check the folder permissions and then try with the IIS permissions.